# one example on naive bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, classification

I see one example on my class notes, but couldn't progress how this reached:

[image]

**Update: the prior probability of two class is assumed to be equal.**

is there any way to calculate this by hands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Bayes formula, $$P(B| (X,Y)=(3,1))=\frac{P((X,Y)=(3,1)|B)P(B)}{P((X,Y)=(3,1))}$$

$P(B)$ is $4/7$ based on number of examples in each class. And, we’ll apply the Naive assumption, i.e. conditional independence, on features given class as follows:

$$P((X,Y)=(3,1)|B) =P(X=3|B)P(Y=1|B)=1/4\times1/2=1/8$$

So, the numerator is 1/14, which is equal to the given answer. But, this is not normalized, so it is not the probability of this sample belonging to class B. However, typically, in Naive Bayes, we only calculate the numerator and decide the class which maximizes it.

Normally, you need to calculate the denominator for a probability, and there you’ll apply total law of probability:

$$P((X,Y)=(3,1)) = P((X,Y)=(3,1)|B)P(B) + P((X,Y)=(3,1)|A)P(A) $$

Here, we proceed similarly for class A. $P(A)=3/7$ and $$P((X,Y)=(3,1)|A)=P(X=3|A)P(Y=1|A)=1/3\times1/3=1/9$$

So,
$$P((X,Y)=(3,1))=1/14+1/9\times3/7=1/14+1/21=5/42$$

When we substitute into the original Bayes formula, we have

$$P(B| (X,Y)=(3,1))=\frac{1/14}{5/42}=3/5$$

**Edit**: If priors P(A) and P(B) are given as equal and not estimated from the data, i.e. they're both 1/2, we'll just substitute 1/2 for them (i.e. P(A) and P(B)) in the above equations, the probability we're interested in is
$$p=\frac{1/8\times1/2}{1/8\times1/2+1/9\times1/2}=9/17$$

Comment: one missed point, how relate this: this new point belong to class B ?

Comment: That probability can be calculated as explained in the final section of the answer, which will not be equal to 1/14. Intuitively, I don’t see that much of certainty as well, i.e. 93% prob the sample is from class A

Comment: very confusing for me. why we need normalization here? would you please complete it step by step for better understanding?

Comment: Ok, I’ll in an hour, this is the best I can do from mobile app right now :) But the normalization is done because of the denominator in the Bayes formula. the denom is the normalization

Comment: I want to check whole steps so I wait for you then discuss. thanks for learn

Comment: is it possible add any reference for normalization?

Comment: It is Bayes Theorem

Comment: Dear Gunes, I see in my note examples that I forget to add here. it mentioned that prior probability for two class A and B here in this example are equal. is it affect solution? if yes please update your answer? would you please clarify me? thanks.

Comment: @JohnatanMorian I’ve appended what happens when priors change